# Duplicate Push Notification using Azure Push Notification

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

- We are implementing Push Notification System for iOS & Android using Azure Notification Hub.
- App registers every time during app launch. Devices are registered for push notification with tags identified by appname_userid. For e.g. Android_1122 where 1122 is an unique user id. The same in an iPhone device will be iPhone_1122.
  A user can have multiple devices, where a push message will be meant to be delivered to all devices having the same tag.
- However there is an issue that we are facing on duplicate push notifications getting delivered for a few users. 
  Every time a user uninstall & re-installs the app, a new token is returned. So, for that given tag, multiple registrations are made leading to duplicate pushes delivered to the same device.
- Have also gone through similar links like the one below. But, not entirely clear as to what is exactly meant by using the Create Registration ID REST API that returns a registrationId without actually creating a registration.
  [azure notification hubs - app uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564354/azure-notification-hubs-app-uninstall)
- Please provide some way to avoid duplicate registrations for the same device.

Below is the code we are using to register.

iOS Devices

```
NSString *mobileServicesURL = @"Endpoint=sb://mobilepushnotificationhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";

SBNotificationHub *hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:mobileServicesURL notificationHubPath:@"notificationhubname"];

[hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:token tags:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iphoneapp_%@", [self getUserID]], nil] completion:^(NSError* error) {
    completion(error);
}];
```

Android Devices

```
private void gcmPush() {
    NotificationsManager.handleNotifications(this, SENDER_ID, MyHandler.class);

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://mobilepushnotificationhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";

    hub = new NotificationHub("notificationhubname", connectionString, this);

    registerWithNotificationHubs();

    // completed Code
}

// Added Method
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void registerWithNotificationHubs() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                String regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

                Log.e("regid RECEIVED ", regid);
                hub.register(regid, "androidapp_" + WhatsOnIndiaConstant.USERId);

                WhatsOnIndiaConstant.notificationHub = hub;
                WhatsOnIndiaConstant.gcmHub = gcm;

            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.e("Exception ", ee.getMessage().toString());
                return ee;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Every time a user uninstall & re-installs the app, a new token is
>   returned. So, for that given tag, multiple registrations are made
>   leading to duplicate pushes delivered to the same device.

As far as I understood, there is only one working device token at a time for `Apple Push Notification Service` (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712968/could-one-ios-application-support-multiple-push-notification-registration)), so you won't have a problem with multiple valid device tokens for one device under iOS, but you could have multiple `Azure Notification Hub` registrations for one device token. To avoid this, you have to check if there are already registrations for the concrete device token and if so, reuse and clean them up:

[ASP.NET WebAPI-Backend example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-notify-users/):

```
// POST api/register
// This creates a registration id
public async Task<string> Post(string handle = null)
{
    // make sure there are no existing registrations for this push handle (used for iOS and Android)
    string newRegistrationId = null;

    if (handle != null)
    {
        var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle, 100);

        foreach (RegistrationDescription registration in registrations)
        {
            if (newRegistrationId == null)
            {
                newRegistrationId = registration.RegistrationId;
            }
            else
            {
                await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
            }
        }
    }

    if (newRegistrationId == null) newRegistrationId = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();

    return newRegistrationId;
}
```

---

With `Google Cloud Messaging`, it seems you can have multiple working GCM registration IDs, so you have to take care of this. GCM has something called "[**`Canonical IDs`**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)":

> If a bug in the app triggers multiple registrations for the same
>   device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with
>   duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your app. This is
>   the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

Comment: Perfect - you made my day. Didn't know that GCM uses multiple working deviceTokens! Now my push services work!

Comment: But this code will miss notifications sent in between deletion and creation.